# Firebase rules not updating with multiple databases

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have two databases. For now they will use the same rules, say, that no reads and writes are allowed at all.

In my `firebase.json` file I have:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "firestore": [
    {
      "database": "default",
      "rules": "firestore.default.rules",
      "indexes": "firestore.default.indexes.json"
    },
    {
      "database": "db-2",
      "rules": "firestore.db-2.rules",
      "indexes": "firestore.db-2.indexes.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

However when I run `firebase deploy`, it seems to not add any new rules / show that any updates have been made. I checked this with Google Cloud Console and Firebase Console.

I did simply just copy the old `firebase.rules` file and rename it twice to get the separate database rules files. From the docs ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-multiple-dbs)), I think I've done this correct.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: When you fire off the deploy, do you see any abnormal log messages such as a "HTTP 429 Quota" error?

Comment: Does `firebase deploy --only firestore:rules` have any effect?

Comment: @samthecodingman Unfortunately there are no abnormal log messages and that command doesn't seem to do much. The output when I run it is: `i  deploying firestore` and that's it.

Comment: The deployment process is asynchronous which causes the logs to appear out of order, so make sure to look over the entire log for anything of interest. Make sure to also check the logs in your Google Cloud console to see if anything shows up there. Honestly, it sounds like you've hit some sort of edge case and it might be better to just raise a ticket with Firebase directly.

Comment: @samthecodingman Yeah so the logs show only the commands that worked. Any requests that tried to give different rules to different databases aren't being shown in the log.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I noticed that the problem could be in the word 'default', which in reality in the GCP-firestore database is (default).
It seems that the Firebase CLI gives no error in the command

"firebase deploy --only firestore:default" then also "firebase deploy"

I tried to make this change:

the line

```
"database": "default"
```

to

```
"database": "(default)"
```

and

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:"(default)"
```

This procedure worked for me

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

Try `firebase deploy --only firestore`.

If you want to deploy only the database named `foo`, use `firebase deploy --only firestore:foo`.
After the ":" is the name of the database.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/25a7239b6a7a70c5c912795517f788442d71ee08/src/firestore/fsConfig.ts#L26-L28

Also, `default` must be `(default)`.